# I want to set up some conditions on Thymeleaf templates like this. But it doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

```
<li th:if="${#lists.contains(pages, 'User Management') or #lists.contains(pages, 'Retirees') or lists.contains(pages, 'Verify Account')"></li>
```

How do i make this code correctly work?

Comment: `lists.contains(pages, 'Verify Account')` -> You missed the `#` keyword

Comment: #lists.contains(pages, 'User Management') --># keyword is there but not working..

Comment: On the last condiiton of `Verify Account`

Comment: thanks it's working fine

Comment: You can provide a checkmark...

Answer (score 0):

`lists.contains(pages, 'Verify Account')` -> You missed the `#` keyword so the expression is invalid